# Time complexity of returning every path in a binary tree whose path equals the target sum

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, binary-tree

I solved LeetCode challenge [113. Path Sum II](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-ii/description/):

> Given the root of a binary tree and an integer targetSum, return all root-to-leaf paths where the sum of the node values in the path equals targetSum. Each path should be returned as a list of the node values, not node references.
>
> A root-to-leaf path is a path starting from the root and ending at any leaf node. A leaf is a node with no children.

This is my code:

```js
var pathSum = function(root, targetSum) {
    let paths = [];
    if(root === null) {
        return [];
    }
    getAllSumPaths(root, [], paths, targetSum);
    return paths;
}; 

function getAllSumPaths(root, currPath, paths, targetSum) {
    if(root.left === null && root.right === null) {
        if(targetSum - root.val === 0) {
            currPath.push(root.val);
            paths.push([...currPath]);
            currPath.pop();
        }
        return;
    }
    currPath.push(root.val);
    if(root.left !== null){
        getAllSumPaths(root.left, currPath, paths, targetSum - root.val);
    }
    if(root.right !== null){
        getAllSumPaths(root.right, currPath, paths, targetSum - root.val);        
    }
    currPath.pop();
}
```

Initially I figured the time complexity would just be O(n) where n is the number of nodes in the tree. However, while writing this, I had to use the spread operator to create a new instance of a valid path to add to my paths array by doing `paths.push([...currPath]);` because the subsequent pop() calls would modify the paths already pushed and I would get empty paths in the end.

But I found that the spread operation has an O(n) time complexity where n would be the size of the path. I'm not sure how that factors into the time complexity of the algorithm. Any ideas? and is there another way to write this so I don't have an O(n) operation when I find a valid path?

Comment: It factors in as `O(n + log n * x)`, where `x` is the expected number of paths matching your condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had to use the spread operator to create a new instance of a valid path to add to my paths array by doing `paths.push([...currPath])`

Yes, this is needed, as otherwise you only have one path that keeps on mutating.

> the spread operation has an O(n) time complexity where n would be the size of the path. I'm not sure how that factors into the time complexity of the algorithm.

You are right that the  in that O() is limited to the size of the path, which is limited by the height of the tree. On average the height of a tree is O(log) where  is the number of nodes in the tree, so that spread operation has an average time complexity of O(log).

Since the challenge description says that node values can be both positive and negative, there may also be cases where a suitable path can be extended to another suitable path (by adding a total value of 0).

> is there another way to write this so I don't have an O(n) operation when I find a valid path?

No. The expected output has to include all paths, and since these paths are all distinct they each occupy distinct memory for the node references they contain.

Take for example this tree, and with 5 as the required sum

```
                  0
               /       \
              5         1
             / \       / \
           -2  -1     4   2
           /   /     /   / 
          2   1     0   2
```

Then the expected output would (in any order) be:

```
[[0,5],[0,5,-2,2],[0,5,-1,1],[5],[5,-2,2],[5,-1,1],[0,1,4],[0,1,2,2],[1,4],[1,2,2]]
```

...where the numbers are actually node instances.

Note that there are 29 nodes in that output, while the tree only has 11 nodes. Many nodes appear more than once, because they are part of different paths.

The time complexity is thus directly related to the size of the output.

The very worst case is an input of a perfect binary tree, where each node value is 0 and the expected sum is 0. That means that all possible (downward) paths (without any restriction caused by the sum) should be included in the output:

```
                  0
              /       \
             0         0
            / \       / \
           0   0     0   0
          /\   /\   /\   /\
         0  0 0  0 0  0 0  0
```

The paths can be categorised by their length:

- There are  paths of length 1
- There are −1 paths of length 2
- There are −3 paths of length 3

  ...
- There are −(2−1) paths of length

(the above tree has  + −1 + −3 + −7 = 4−11 = 49 paths)

So ∑<sub><sub>=0</sub></sub><sup><sup>log</sup></sup> (−(2−1))
= ∑<sub><sub>=0</sub></sub><sup><sup>log</sup></sup> (+1−2)

Let's split the summation into two sums to take that subtraction apart:

= (+1)log − ∑<sub><sub>=0</sub></sub><sup><sup>log</sup></sup> 2

This summation is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula)

= (+1)log − 2<sup>log−1</sup>

= (+1)log − /2

= O(log)